# Method of UINavigationController to add a view controller to navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Which method of the UINavigationController is used to add a view controller to navigation stack in swift?

Comment: Please show UINavigationControllerDelegate Method func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the following method is used to push `UIViewController` to `UINavigationController`'s navigation stack

```
pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

This is implemented inside your `CustomViewController` class in the following way:

```
let someVC: CustomViewController = CustomViewController() // this is one way of initializing it
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someVC, animated: true)
```

The following is another method which can be used to add a `UIViewController` to `UINavigationController` stack

```
setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], animated: Bool)
```